# Anchor: useAnchorWallet vs solana's useWallet

Tags: anchor, solana-program, frontend

I was just wondering if I would be able to substitute Solana's `useWallet()` instead of `useAnchorWallet()` when interacting with a smart contract using Anchor on the front end.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use the `AnchorWallet` from `useAnchorWallet()` to set up Anchor in the frontend. They are not directly compatible. The `Wallet` from `useWallet` has more functionality, but can't be used to set up the `AnchorProvider`.

```
  const wallet = useAnchorWallet()
  const { connection } = useConnection()

  const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, wallet, {})

  setProvider(provider)
  const program = new Program(IDL as Idl, programId)
```

From `useAnchorWallet()`

```
export interface AnchorWallet {
    publicKey: PublicKey;
    signTransaction(transaction: Transaction): Promise<Transaction>;
    signAllTransactions(transactions: Transaction[]): Promise<Transaction[]>;
}
export declare function useAnchorWallet(): AnchorWallet | undefined;
```

From `useWallet()`

```
export interface Wallet {
    adapter: Adapter;
    readyState: WalletReadyState;
}
export interface WalletContextState {
    autoConnect: boolean;
    wallets: Wallet[];
    wallet: Wallet | null;
    publicKey: PublicKey | null;
    connecting: boolean;
    connected: boolean;
    disconnecting: boolean;
    select(walletName: WalletName): void;
    connect(): Promise<void>;
    disconnect(): Promise<void>;
    sendTransaction(transaction: Transaction, connection: Connection, options?: SendTransactionOptions): Promise<TransactionSignature>;
    signTransaction: SignerWalletAdapterProps['signTransaction'] | undefined;
    signAllTransactions: SignerWalletAdapterProps['signAllTransactions'] | undefined;
    signMessage: MessageSignerWalletAdapterProps['signMessage'] | undefined;
}
export declare const WalletContext: import("react").Context<WalletContextState>;
export declare function useWallet(): WalletContextState;
```

Answer (score 2):

My short answer is you cant.

- `useWallet` for UI state (e.g: wallet name, wallet connected)
- `useAnchorWallet` for interacting with anchor (e.g: calling solana program using anchor provider)

`useWallet` wallet is not compatible with anchor while `useAnchorWallet` doesn't have wallet state.

more info of wallet vs anchor wallet type:
https://solana-labs.github.io/wallet-adapter/interfaces/_solana_wallet_adapter_react.WalletContextState.html

Comment: This isn't quite true - `useWallet` can be used to sign transactions, see the interface here: https://solana-labs.github.io/wallet-adapter/interfaces/_solana_wallet_adapter_react.WalletContextState.html#signTransaction If you don't need Anchor (eg. you're just writing transactions talking to system/token program etc) then you don't need to use `useAnchorWallet`